# Symfony : Validate email domain in User Form Register

Tags: php, symfony, validation, email, doctrine

I am trying to validate a user email domain in a register form.Before I validated in this way with FormHandler -> Class StudentRegisterHandler.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\User;

use AppBundle\Form\FormHandler; 
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v; 
use AppBundle\Services\UserManager;
use AppBundle\Form\FormHandler; 
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v; 
use AppBundle\Services\UserManager;

class StudentRegisterHandler extends FormHandler { 
    public function handle(){ 
      parent::handle();

        if(!$this->isSubmitted()){
            return;
    }

    $username = $this->createParamValidationResult('username');
    $email = $this->createParamValidationResult('email');
    $password = $this->createParamValidationResult('password');

    $usernameValidator = v::allOf(
        v::length(5,20),
        v::regex("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_]{0,2}[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/")
    );

    $emailValidator = v::allOf(
        v::email(),
        v::oneOf(
            v::endsWith("@yahoo.com"),
            v::endsWith("@gmail.com")
        )
    );
    return;
}
}
```

Now I'm adding more than 100 email domains list (outlook.com,uad.co, ect) and I don't want to validate in the same way so I created an Entity where I store all those email domains.So now I am stuck to find a solution how to validate those email domain which are store in my Entity($id,$emailDomain). I am trying to use a query validation from the Repository if that email domain exist in Db  but don't know how to add the parameter $emailDomain for the Register Form validation and how to relate with the method from the UserRepository.php.
Example :

```
$emailValidator = v::allOf(
    v::email(),
    v::oneOf(
        v::endsWith("$emailDomain")
    )
);
```

This is how my  RegistrationController.php is :

```
  <?php

// src/AppBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\EducatorProfile;
use AppBundle\Entity\StudentProfile;
use AppBundle\Form\User\StudentRegisterHandler;
use AppBundle\Form\User\EducatorRegisterHandler;
use AppBundle\Form\ValidationResponse;
use AppBundle\Services\UserManager;
use AppBundle\Util\TokenGenerator;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * @Route("/register")
 */
class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/student", name="registration_student_register")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserManager $userManager
     * @param TokenGenerator $tokenGenerator
     * @return Response
     */
    public function studentRegisterAction(Request $request, UserManager $userManager, TokenGenerator $tokenGenerator)
    {
        /** @var StudentRegisterHandler $formHandler*/
        $formHandler = new StudentRegisterHandler($this->container,$request);
        $formHandler->handle();

        /** @var ValidationResponse $validationResponse */
        $validationResponse = $formHandler->getValidationResponse();

        if($formHandler->isSubmitted() && $formHandler->isValid()){
            $user = $userManager->createUser(
                $validationResponse->getValue('username'),
                $validationResponse->getValue('email'),
                $validationResponse->getValue('password'),
                false
            );
        $user->setConfirmationToken($tokenGenerator->generateToken());


        $studentProfile->setUser($user);

        $userManager->saveUser($user);
        $userManager->saveProfile($studentProfile);



    return $this->render('registration/register_student.html.twig', array(
        'validationResponse' => $validationResponse
    ));
}
```

I am opened for any suggestion.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the built-in email validator with the parameters `checkMX` or `checkHost` set to `true`.

Here is the basic usage as written in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints/Email.html#checkmx):

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Author.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email.",
     *     checkMX = true
     * )
     */
     protected $email;
}
```

What I'm writing below is purely theoretical, I've not tested it, but you may be able to use something like this in your code:

```
$emailValidator = v::allOf(
    v::email(['checkMX' => 'true'])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about building a custom ValidationConstraint ? ValidationConstraints are services (like basically everything in symfony). Which means they can access your database (e.g. via doctrine), get all valid domains and then perform their validations accordingly.

This should help you get started: [How to Create custom Validation Constraints (Official Doc)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)